# How to calculate number of different number of characters in a string data in c++?

Tags: c++

I am able to count the number of characters in my string using length() function. 
But i want to calculate the number of different characters in my string.
i.e. say string is "Hello world"
So here number of different strings are H,e,l,o, ,w,r,d.
so 8 different characters.

Comment: Adding every single character into a std::map<char,int> should do the trick.

Comment: That would be quite wasteful/inefficient. An array will be fine if you don't care about Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do is a method called frequency checking. Basically create a vector of size 128. Go through the string and for every character, increment the frequency that matches its ASCII value. Finally, iterate over the freq vector and count how many non zero entries you have. Code should look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string s = "Hello World";
vector<int>freq(128);

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    freq[s[i]]++;

int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    if(freq[i] > 0)
        counter++;

cout << counter << "\n";
}
```

Vector of size 128 works fine because ASCII codes only go from 0 to 127.

Another way is to initialize a `std::set` and insert every character of the string into that one at a time. Finally, output the size of the set. This works because set doesn't allow duplicate entries. The code for this looks like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Hello World";
    set<char>x;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        x.insert(s[i]);

    cout << x.size() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Except this isn't called hashing :)

Comment: The question doesn't specify ASCII, though. Use `CHAR_MAX` instead of assuming 127.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it's using the identity function as a hash

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of unique characters, you can use `sd::sort` followed by `std::unique`. It will reshuffle the contents and return an iterator to the last unique character in your string. Subtract `begin()` and you have the result.

Comment: `std::unique` only works in a already sorted collection. So `std::sort` should be called first.

Comment: To put it more precisely, `std::unique` only shuffles consecutive equal elements, so to achieve the effect the OP is after, `std::sort` should be called first.

Comment: @john: Well, it works in a non-sorted collection too, but the result will be different (it only removes adjacent duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

I think that an unordered_map is the best way to achieve that.

Here is the code if you want the total number of char in a string, grouped by unique chars.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s="test string";
    unordered_map<char,int> map;

    for (const char &c: s) { //for each char in string
        map[c]++;           
    }
    for (auto &e: map)  //for each unique char in map
            cout<<"char: "<<e.first<<" number: "<<e.second<<endl;

return 0;

    }
```

**Output**

```
char: n number: 1
char: e number: 1
char: i number: 1
char: t number: 3
char: s number: 2
char:   number: 1
char: g number: 1
char: r number: 1
```

But if you want only the total number of unique chars

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s="test string";
    unordered_map<char,int> map;

    for (const char &c: s) {
        map[c]++;
    }
    int count =0;
    for (auto &e: map)
       count++;

    cout<<"Unique chars: "<<count<<endl;

}
```

**Output**

```
Unique chars: 8
```

Comment: This has terrible memory/storage complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can write your own functions to deal with that like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string uniqueChars(string str) {
  string newStr = "";
  bool arr[128];
  for(int i = 0;i < 128; i++) {
    arr[i] = false;
  }
  char c;
  for(int i = 0, n = str.length();i < n; i++) {
    c = str[i];
    if(c < 0 || c > 127) {
      continue;
    }
    if(!arr[c]) {
      arr[c] = true;
      newStr += c;
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

int main(void) {
  string a = "Hello It's a wonderful world";
  string b = uniqueChars(a);
  cout << a << " => " << a.length() << "\n" <<
    b << " => " << b.length();
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello It's a wonderful world => 28
Helo It'sawndrfu => 16
```

Comment: This has terrible algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Unfortunately, it's true, the uniqueChars loops over the string and on each iteration calls contains which loops over the string once more on each time, ok I have edited my post to be better

Comment: That's better, but initialise `arr` to something (zeroes?) and all you need really is an array of `bool`. Why 129 not 128? And a `char` can have negative values you may wish to filter out or handle to avoid bad memory accesses.

Comment: Yeah good idea to use bool, since I don't need the value in the array to be exact char, ok I will edit it again ;)

Comment: You still need to initialise the array otherwise you're comparing to unknown values.

Comment: Yeah that's too, although my compiler is assigning the default value, but we should not depend on that, I have fixed it, thank you for your revising :)

Comment: The compiler won't be assigning it anything, that's just pure chance :)

Comment: Well I guess I'm lucky then :D

Comment: Or unlucky... ;)